# How to get selected radio button value from question1 activity page to next page

Tags: android, eclipse, radio-button

i am developing a quiz using mobile application. currently, i am having problems on how to       retrieve selected radio button from previous page. i want the selected radio button value to be displayed on the next page. below is my code in xml and java.

question1. java

```
public class question1 extends Activity {
    private Button Button2;
    public RadioButton r1,r2,r3;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.question1); 

        r1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb1);
        r2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb2);
        r3 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb3);

        //Button2
        Button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button2.setOnClickListener((new OnClickListener() {                 
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),question2.class);
                intent.putExtra("r1",r1.isSelected());
                intent.putExtra("r2",r2.isSelected());
                intent.putExtra("r3",r3.isSelected());
                startActivityForResult(intent,0);               
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

this is my code in question1.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="452dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@drawable/clay" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:text="YANG MANA SATUKAH DI ANTARA AYAT-AYAT BERIKUT YANG BENAR ?"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/radioButton2"
                    android:text="A.Tanah liat yang leper lebih berat" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/radioButton3"
                    android:text=" B. Kedua-dua tanah liat adalah sama berat" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioButton2"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
                    android:text="C.Bola tanah liat lebih berat" />
            </RadioGroup>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:background="@drawable/nextnext" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my code for the second page that i want the selected radio button value to be displayed.

question2. java

```
  public class question2 extends Activity
  {
  private Button Button2;
  public RadioButton r1,r2,r3,r4,r5;
  public RadioGroup rg1,rg2;
  public String a2,b2,total;

  public TextView output ;



    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.question2);



   output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
   r1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb1);

   r2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb2);
   r3 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb3);

   r4 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb4);
   r5 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb5);
   rg1 = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);     
   rg2 = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup2);

   Object RadioButton;
   r1= (RadioButton).getValue();
   r2 =(RadioButon).getValue();
   r3 =(RadioButon).getValue();



 //Button2
        Button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button2.setOnClickListener((new OnClickListener()
        {

            public void onClick(View view) 
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),question3.class);


                startActivityForResult(intent,0);
            }
        }
            ));

        {
                switch(rg2.getCheckedRadioButtonId()){

                case R.id.rb4:
                    if (r4.isChecked()){
                        //a2 =0;

                    }
                        break;



                case R.id.rb5:
                    if (r5.isChecked()){
                        //b2 = 1;


                    }
                        break;

                       //total = rg1.getCheckedRadioButtonId()+rg2.getCheckedRadioButtonId()  ;    
                }}
        //receive the arguments from the previous Activity
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras==null) {
            return;
        }

        output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);

        Bundle data = this.getIntent().getExtras();

         r1=data.getValue(r1);
         r2=data.getValue(r2);
         r3=data.getValue(r3);

         double result = 0;

        if (r1 == "")
        {
            result+ = 1;
        }
        else if (r2 == "true"){
            result+ = 0;}

        else if (r3=="true")
        {
            result+ = 0;
        }
        else {
            result + =0;
        }

        }
        }

        }
```

question2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="452dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.13"
                android:src="@drawable/soklan2" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radioGroup2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView4" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="A. Ya" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioGroup1"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1"
                    android:text="B. Tidak" />
            </RadioGroup>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup2"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="Result"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:background="@drawable/nextnext" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I would like to know, how to retrieve the value from question 1 and displayed it on question2 page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use:

```
r1.setChecked(getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("r1"));
r2.setChecked(getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("r2"));
r3.setChecked(getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("r3"));
```

You may also need to change the code where you put the values:

```
intent.putExtra("r1",r1.isChecked());
intent.putExtra("r2",r2.isChecked());
intent.putExtra("r3",r3.isChecked());
```

You should also probably look at this code:

```
Object RadioButton;
r1 = (RadioButton).getValue();
r2 = (RadioButon).getValue();
r3 = (RadioButon).getValue();
```

I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish here. And it should probably be removed to keep the refferences to your `RadioButton` Objects

Comment: i got this error "- Incompatible operand types RadioButton and String"

Comment: You can use `r1.isChecdked()` if you want to test whether a `RadioButton` is checked. You should not try some kind of String conversion and test against the String. Just use the boolean value which is already there.

Comment: how to get value on the next page?

Answer (score 0):

In you second activity , get the values from intent extras:

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
 boolean r1Value = intent.getBooleanExtra("r1",false);
 r1.setChecked(r1Value );
```

Comment: i have tried using this code. but after i run the application on emulator, it got an error which is cannot go to next page